# Rubyzip: Export zip file directly to S3 without writing tmpfile to disk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, zip, rubyzip

I have this code, which writes a zip file to disk, reads it back, uploads to s3, then deletes the file:

```ruby
compressed_file = some_temp_path

Zip::ZipOutputStream.open(compressed_file) do |zos|
  some_file_list.each do |file|
    zos.put_next_entry(file.some_title)
    zos.print IO.read(file.path)
  end
end # Write zip file

s3 = Aws::S3.new(S3_KEY, S3_SECRET)
bucket = Aws::S3::Bucket.create(s3, S3_BUCKET)
bucket.put("#{BUCKET_PATH}/archive.zip", IO.read(compressed_file), {}, 'authenticated-read')

File.delete(compressed_file)
```

This code works already but what I want is to **not create the zip file** anymore, to save a few steps. I was wondering if there is a way to export the zipfile data directly to s3 without having to first create a tmpfile, read it back, then delete it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I just found the answer to my question.

It's [Zip::ZipOutputStream.write_buffer](https://github.com/aussiegeek/rubyzip/blob/master/lib/zip/zip_output_stream.rb#L54). I'll check this out and update this answer when I get it working.

**Update**

It does work. My code is like this now:

```
compressed_filestream = Zip::ZipOutputStream.write_buffer do |zos|
  some_file_list.each do |file|
    zos.put_next_entry(file.some_title)
    zos.print IO.read(file.path)
  end
end # Outputs zipfile as StringIO

s3 = Aws::S3.new(S3_KEY, S3_SECRET)
bucket = Aws::S3::Bucket.create(s3, S3_BUCKET)

compressed_filestream.rewind
bucket.put("#{BUCKET_PATH}/archive.zip", compressed_filestream.read, {}, 'authenticated-read')
```

The `write_buffer` returns a [StringIO](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html) and needs to [rewind](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html#method-i-rewind) the stream first before `read`ing it. Now I don't need to create and delete the tmpfile.

I'm just wondering now if `write_buffer` would be more memory extensive or heavier than `open`? Or is it the other way around?

Comment: What is `some_file_list` ?

Comment: I'm guessing its something like.. `some_file_list = Zip::ZipFile.open(zipped_file)`

Comment: For those confused why you're getting errors like `NameError: uninitialized constant Zip::ZipOutputStream`, it's because nowadays the class is called `Zip::OutputStream`.